# Google Sign-in can't access onsuccess function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-signin

I'm trying to allow users to login to my site using Google Sign-in. When I follow their instructions everything works like so:

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn">
  sign in with google
</div>

<script>
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  do stuff here
}
</script>
```

However as you can see, this uses a 'script' block side by side with the markup.

I am using System.JS and I wanted to know how I can have the div.g-signin2 to have access to a function in my System JS module. Another thing I tried was to listen to the 'data-onsuccess' event, but to no success.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try moving the  before the div? Like this:

```
<script>
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  do stuff here
}
</script>

<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn">
  sign in with google
</div>
```

Comment: Position not an issue here.